# How can I set Extra Data into Access Token in Authorization code flow

Tags: oauth-2.0, dotnetopenauth

I am implementing a OAuth2 provider using DotNetOpenAuth.
Using implicit flow, I was capable of passing extra data to function `CreateAccessToken` (`IAuthorizationServerHost`), inside the param `(IAccessTokenRequest accessTokenRequestMessage)` and assign that to the token:

```
accessToken.ExtraData.Add("DeptID", accessTokenRequestMessage.ExtraData["DeptID"].ToString());
```

I accomplished it adding the info inside `EndUserAuthorizationRequest` in Auhtorize endpoint.

The issue is that using authorization code flow, and doing the same thing, the param `(IAccessTokenRequest accessTokenRequestMessage)` always has an empty collection of ExtraData.

I suppose that it is because using this flow there is a second call to Token endpoint, and the information is lost.

How could I pass this information to CreateAccessToken function?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have tried to retrieve this information from a cookie, but the cookie is lost when calling Token endpoint. It seems that DNOA is using a web client behind the scenes when calling Token endpoint in ProcessUserAuthorization(). Any idea?

Comment: It is supposed to be implemented like:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/dotnetopenid/ExtraData/dotnetopenid/acqpZfDlvKE/tGSdGs_OyskJ

But doing this I get Bad Request answer (Protocol error).
AuthorizationServer as;
var response = as.PrepareApproveAuthorizationRequest(req, username, scopes, callback);
response.ExtraData["Username"] = username;
return as.Channel.PrepareResponse(response).AsActionResult();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I achieved to pass information to the token creation was using the User property:

```
var response = this.AuthServer.PrepareApproveAuthorizationRequest(AuthorizationRequest, userInfoString);
```

I have passed a encrypted string of JSON serialization of the information needed. Then, from CreateAccessToken function I've retrieved the value using Reflection over IAccessTokenRequest parameter.

It is not a solution as elegant as I wish, but at least it worked!